# Waitress installed via pip, but cannot be executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, waitress

Overall, pip is working fine on my server. I have just installed the package `waitress` and the installation seems successful. I checked it with `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze | grep waitress
waitress==2.1.0
```

Waitress also can be imported via python3:

```
>>> import waitress
>>>
```

However, `waitress-serve` cannot be executed:

```
$ waitress-serve
Command 'waitress-serve' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install python3-waitress
Please ask your administrator.
```

I am not a root user on this server. Could this be a reason why the package was installed partially, or am I speculating here?

Since I am not authorized to run `apt install` and since the simple `pip` install worked in my virtualenv, I would like to be able to get this to work without using the suggested `apt install python3-waitress` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The conclusion is that, while it is installed both inside and outside virtualenv, it is only actually executable inside it.

When installable Python packages give you an actual entry point, generally it will *not* be on your path.

When you use a virtual environment, activating the environment puts various parts of that environment onto the path temporarily. This is intended to ensure that commands like `python` or `python3` run the environment's Python, but it also allows those entry points to be found on the path.

A system Python installation (here I mean, not just a Python that comes with your operating system, but also one that you install manually after the fact - but *not* a virtual environment) will generally not have its library folders on the path by default - only enough to make `python` and `pip` work. (On Windows, often even these are not added to the path; instead, a program `py` is placed in the Windows installation folder, and it does the work of looking for Python executables.) Even if you are allowed to install things directly into a system Python (and you should normally not do this if you can avoid it, even if you're allowed to), they won't be *findable* there.

Of course, you could execute these things just fine by explicitly specifying their paths. However, the normally correct approach is to just ensure that, when you want to run the program, the same virtual environment is activated into which you installed the package.

(On my system, I have one main "sandbox" virtual environment that I use for all my projects - unless I am specifically testing the installation process, or testing how the code works on a different version of Python. Then I use a wrapper script to open a terminal window, navigate to a folder that contains all my projects, and activate the environment.)

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this one, because I fairly recently switched to Linux and I've noticed that Python installations are structured quite differently on Linux vs Windows.

Comment: It actually worked! It turns out that the waitress executable is found in `~/.local/bin`. When I specify that path for the command, it runs fine!

Answer (score 1):

if `waitress` is installed inside a virtual environment, I think you may have accidentally (or not) gotten out of said virtual environment.

If you are running a virtual environment, you can try the following commands, one after the other:

```sh
source venv/bin/activate #venv is assumed to be the name of the virtual environment you are using. 
pip install waitress
waitress-serve
```

anytime you need to use waitress you will need to activate the virtual environment yet again:

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
waitress-serve
```

**Please take note I am assuming you are running in a Linux environment**

If this is not the issue you are facing, then feel free to expaund a bit more on your question.

*Edit: Installing with pip and running it worked perfectly on my virtualenv; see the picture below, running on python 3.8.10*

[image: picture with waitress being called]

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul! I think I have made my phrasing a bit confusing, but rest assured: I used `pip install waitress` and `pip freeze` outside of my virtualenv. The conclusion is that, while it is installed both inside and outside virtualenv, it is only actually executable inside it.

Comment: Huh, still weird. 
Are the versions of Python being used in and out of the virtual environment the same?

Still on the same, can you specify which Python versions you are using on both ends ? I have updated my answer to specify the version in case that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through this with me, Paul. I've just checked: both inside and outside venv, the python version is 3.8.10.

Comment: Lee, no problem. Kind of bored anyway so I should give this a shot. My python environment is the same yours and waitress is running just fine both in and out of the virtual envs. I can see it runs on CPython, my best guess would be the problem is somewhere in there, because it seems to support both Unix based and Windows Operating Systems.

Comment: Also, I have never used waitress. Just looking through it and the only difference that might occur between the two environments is probably something CPython specific. Still digging for other options. Have you used CPython before in your default Python environment(the one without virtualenv)?

Comment: Hello again Paul. I return after checking the other answer provided by Karl Knetchel, and that seems to have been the issue! The executable is installed, it's just not in a folder that's part of the `path` variable.

Comment: That is great !! Awesome to hear you found a way out.